# Do superclass instances exist when a new subclass object is created?

Tags: java

Does the JVM create superclass instances when new a subclass object is created?  In the example below why does `super.setName("Buddy")` succeed?  Is there an instance of `Pet` after creating a `new Dog()`?

```
public class MainDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pet pet = new Dog();
        System.out.println(pet.getName());//it will print Buddy
    }
}
public class Pet {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class Dog extends Pet {
    public Dog() {
        super.setName("Buddy");
    }
}
```

I changed the constructor of Dog and Pet like below

```
public Pet() {
    System.out.println("this is Pet's constructor");
}
public Dog() {       
    super.setName("Buddy");
    System.out.println("this is Dog's constructor");
}
```

the result in console is

```
this is Pet's constructor
this is Dog's constructor
Buddy
```

It looks like the jvm creates a Pet?

I added code again into Pet and Dog like below

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+".hashCode="+this.hashCode());
```

the result is

```
this is Pet's constructor
com.bt.java.project.Dog.hashCode=27189676
this is Dog's constructor
com.bt.java.project.Dog.hashCode=27189676
Buddy
```

Their hashCode is same.So it means there is only one instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute

```
new Dog()
```

there is only *one* object that's physically created, namely an instance of the `Dog` class. This instance, however, also contains all the information necessary so that it can be used as a `Pet`. It inherits all the non-private fields/methods contained in `Pet`, but also may add *additional* fields/methods specific to a dog. For this reason, an object is also said to be an instance of all its superclasses, but that doesn't change the fact that only one object was ever created (which I think is your question, fundamentally).

You should think of a `Dog` object like this:

```
+---------------+
|  +---------+  |
|  | Pet     |  |
|  | fields  |  |
|  | and     |  |
|  | methods |  |
|  +---------+  |
|               |
|  Dog          |
|  fields       |
|  and          |
|  methods      |
+---------------+
```

It's all still *one* object, but you are able to *treat it* as a `Pet` by considering only the innermost `Pet` region of the diagram above.

Comment: Does it mean, when Dog's instance is created, it will have a copy of members of its super classes generated in memory and the net number of objects created will be one

Comment: @JeeshuMittal Yes, I think you're on the right track. As I said, it contains all the information needed for it to be used as a `Pet` and some additional information specific to `Dog`. All of this being encapsulated in a single object.

Comment: [This article contains further references and images](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html#instanceinit) maybe they can be linked into the answer

Comment: Yes.this is exactly what i want to ask

Comment: @JeeshuMittal [this site offers some good advices](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/18/must-reads-for-java-developers-from-beginner-to-professional-2/) journey mans list is a complete must read including "clean code", "effective java", "pragmatic programmer", "design patterns (GoF)", "refactorings"

Comment: @arshajii In your diagram  do the fields of Pet include private fields?

Comment: @Mr.Sky The private fields of `Pet` *are* included in the `Dog` instance, but there is no way you can access them directly in the `Dog` class programatically.

Comment: @isi Thankyou very much. it has got really awesome content :)

Comment: @arshajii Please look at the end of my question.Can i say the same hashCode means there is just only one object?

Comment: @Mr.Sky The hash codes don't really prove anything here. Two different objects could potentially have the same identity hash code.

Answer (score 1):

`Dog extends Pet`. That means that a Dog is a Pet. Thus, your class Dog has all the methods of Pet and can use them (at least the public and protected ones).

You might want to start with a tutorial on classes and OOP.

And to answer your question: yes, there is an instance of Pet created (and it is the same as the instance of Dog). You cannot have a Dog that is not a Pet. A Pet that is not a Dog is possible.

For instance you can do:

```
Pet pet = new Dog();
```

Your pet will be a Dog (an instance of Dog), but you will only be able to call the methods from Pet, unless you cast it to a Dog like this:

```
((Dog)pet).someMethodOnlyInDogAndNotInPet();
```

You can even do:

```
Object obj = new Dog();
```

since all objects are derived from Object. I strongly suggest not to do it.

Comment: I would like to see on this answer that the `Pet` object doesn't really exist, only that it can be treated like one.

Comment: @isi but that information would be wrong - the Pet object really exists. It's constructor has been called to create it (during constructor chaining when new Dog() is called)

Comment: My question is does jvm create an instance of Pet when new a Dog?In other words,`super.setName("Buddy")` set which object?

Comment: @Mr.Sky: Yes, it does, but it is the same as the instance of Dog.

Comment: Only one object is created. That object is both a Pet and a Dog at the same time.

Comment: Agree with @KathyA. The `Dog` object exists and it can be treated like a `Pet` object. Take a look at [this article](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html) section "Initialization and inheritance". Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @ivi: of course it can be treated like a Pet object, since IT IS a Pet object! It can also be treated as an Object object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an instance Pet, but it is the same as the instance Dog. You can do:

```
    Dog dog = new Dog("Bleeker");
    Pet myPet = (Pet) dog;
    Pet pet = new Pet("Buddy");

    // this will print the same Object ID twice:
    System.out.println(dog);
    System.out.println(myPet);

    // this will print a different Object ID:
    System.out.println(pet);
```

If you change the implementations like so:

```
public class Pet {
    private String name;

    public Pet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Pet {

    public Dog(String name) {
        // call to constructor of Pet, initializing a Pet instance
        super(name);
        // completion of constructor of Dog, initializing a Dog instance.
    }
}
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(dog.getName()); // will print Bleeker
System.out.println(myPet.getName()); // will print Bleeker
System.out.println(pet.getName()); // will print Buddy
```

Comment: I run the code and  `System.out.println(pet.getName());` also print Bleeker

Comment: Sorry, my example was incorrect. I have tried to make amends with a new example. I think the key of understanding this is constructor chaining, see the comments in the Dog class.